# How to add generator elements to a set() without a loop?

Tags: python, set, generator

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python/231855#231855) it says generators aren't initialized like iterables.

How do you add the elements of a *generator* to a set? Is there a better way than just a `for item in generator` sort of thing and using `setname.add(item)`?

The generator is that returned by a `cursor.execute("SELECT ...")` command to the cursor from a connection to an sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also just do `set(gen)`:

```
>>> set(x**2 for x in range(5))
set([0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
```

(Note that this creates a new set with just the elements in the generator.  You'll need to do something along the lines of unutbu's answer if you want to add the elements to a pre-existing set.)

Comment: Great answer, but if you just want to add the items from the generator, you don't even need the for: `set(my_generator())` will do.

Comment: @tdelaney: I just used a generator comprehension as an example of a generator.  As I said at the beginning `set(gen)` will work for any generator `gen`.

Comment: I interpreted that as passing in the generator function instead of the iterator that is returned by calling the generator. But I see what you mean now!

Comment: @tdelaney: Technically the function is a "generator function" and its return value is the generator.  But yes, the idea was that you would do `gen = generator_func()` and then call `set(gen)`.

Comment: okay, curious, is there a way to do this if the generator `gen` returns tuples `item` and you only want one element of the tuple, `item[0]`?

Comment: @rebecca: You could do `set(item[0] for item in gen)`.

Comment: okay, so the only way is a for loop. that's right, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `update` method:

```
In [3]: x = set()

In [4]: g = (i**2 for i in range(5))

In [6]: x.update(g)

In [7]: x
Out[7]: {0, 1, 4, 9, 16}
```

`update` modifies `x`. If you just want to return a new set you could use `union`:

```
In [8]: x = set()

In [9]: g = (i**2 for i in range(5))

In [10]: x.union(g)
Out[10]: {0, 1, 4, 9, 16}
```

Comment: is that actually different from `for i in g: x.add(i)` in this case? I think that's all `set.update` will do when given a generator, but it may be somehow optimized.

Comment: @AdamSmith: After doing a %timeit test, it appears calling `update` once is slightly quicker than using a Python loop and calling `x.add` many times, but the difference is not very great for large generators. That makes sense since `set.update` is just on call implemented in C (at least in CPython), but under the hood, Python is still looping through the generator.

Comment: You don't need the for inside update either. `my_set.update(my_generator())` works as well.

Comment: @tdelaney: My answer does not use `for` inside `update`. The `for` is simply to define a simple generator.

Comment: @unutbu, sorry about that, i was saw list when i should have seen generator.